# upload image and store in database using ajax in php laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm working in php laravel what i want is to upload an image in a form that is used to add new CATEGORY: category name, description and upload image.

my view is as shown:

```
@extends('layouts.app', ['activePage' => 'category', 'titlePage' => __('Category Management')])

@section('content')

@include('modal.editCategory');

  <div class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <form id="categoryForm">
            @csrf
            @method('post')



            <div class="card ">
              <div class="card-header card-header-primary">
                <h4 class="card-title">{{ __('Add Category') }}</h4>
                <p class="card-category"></p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body ">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                      <a href="{{ route('getFeed') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">{{ __('Back to Feeds') }}</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">{{ __('Name') }}</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                      <input class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="category" id="category" type="text" placeholder="{{ __('Name') }}" value="" required="true" aria-required="true"/>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">{{ __('Description') }}</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                      <textarea class="md-textarea form-control" rows="5" name="desc" id="desc" type="text" placeholder="{{ __('Description') }}" value="" required="true" aria-required="true"></textarea>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="card-footer ml-auto mr-auto">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary newCategory">{{ __('Add Category') }}</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header card-header-primary">
                <h4 class="card-title ">{{ __('Category List') }}</h4>
                <p class="card-category"> {{ __('Here you can manage categories') }}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                @if (session('status'))
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <div class="alert alert-success">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                          <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                        </button>
                        <span>{{ session('status') }}</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                @endif
                <div class="table-responsive ">
                  <table class="table display responsive nowrap table-striped" id="category-datatable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead class=" text-primary ">
                    <th>
                          {{ __('No') }}
                      </th>
                    <th>
                          {{ __('Name') }}
                      </th>
                      <th>
                          {{ __('Description') }}
                      </th>
                      <th class="text-right">
                        {{ __('Actions') }}
                      </th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

    </div>
  </div>

@endsection
```

I used ajax to submit value from view to controller as shown below:

// add category

```
 $('.newCategory').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = $("#categoryForm").serialize();
        $('.error-msg').html('');
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            url: baseUrl + 'addCategory',
            type: 'GET',
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
                localStorage.setItem("swal",
                    swal({
                        title: "Success!",
                        text: "Category Added",
                        type: "success",
                        timer: 3000,
                        showConfirmButton: false
                    })
                );
                location.reload();
                localStorage.getItem("swal");


            }

        });

    });
```

An this is my controller:

```
public function addCategory(Request $request)
    {
        $name=$request->input('category');
        $desc=$request->input('desc');
        $created_at=Carbon::now();
        $updated_at=Carbon::now();
        $data=array('name'=>$name,'description'=>$desc,'created_at'=>$created_at,'updated_at'=>$updated_at);
        Category::insert($data);
    }
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Does the image need to be stored in the DB? Why not store the image on the server and then save the directory of the image in the DB?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Maybe you could remove some unrelated parts of your code? Please consider to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for some inspiration!

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question but... Storing files in a database is a really bad idea. Store it in S3, on your hard drive, wherever else, but not in a DB. In your DB you should store only a filename or something else that can identify your file.

Comment: I think he still beginners to know about advantages and disadvantages of storing files in database or cloud service, let' help him how implement it with current code , for @kuku try to search in the net before asking questions  here: follow this tutorial :https://www.cloudways.com/blog/the-basics-of-file-upload-in-php/

Comment: yeah i just need to store the filename in database

Comment: what is the issue you have facing with this code